# Python: Replace "wrong" floats by integers inside string

Tags: python, string, replace, floating-point, integer

I'm trying to **replace** all **useless floats** in a **string** (1.0, 2.0 etc.) by **integers**. So I'd turn a string like `"15.0+abc-3"` to `"15+abc-3"`.
Do you know a way to do that?

*I hope you understood my idea. If you didn't feel free to ask.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=\d)\.0+\b
```

You can simple use this and replace by `empty string` via `re.sub`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/22

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<=\d)\.0+\b')
test_str = "15.0+abc-3"
subst = ""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the other one was a bit faster :P

Comment: @Unknown there is it capturing a group which we dont need.

Comment: But both are only working, with number with only one 0 behind. Do one for infinite 0s, and you're the winner ^^ EDIT: Got it my self. You'll get the vote anyway for giving the link :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` :

```
>>> s="15.0+abc-3"
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\b(\d+)\.0+\b',r'\1',s)
'15+abc-3'

>>> s="15.0000+abc-333.0+er1102.05"
>>> re.sub(r'\b(\d+)\.0+\b',r'\1',s)
'15+abc-333+er1102.05'
```

`\d+` will match any digit with length 1 or more and in `sub` function `(\d+)\.0` will match the numbers with useless decimal zero.that will be replaced by the first group `\1` that is your number (within capture group `(\d+)`).

And `\b` is word boundary that makes your regex doesn't match some numbers like `1102.05`!

Comment: But it's only working with one 0 behind. Can you do one for infinite 0s?

Comment: @Unknown Yeah, just add `+` after `0`. fixed!

Comment: I'm sorry I can't vote for both, but the other guy answered that faster :/ Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Unknown It's OK buddy! don't care about this imaginary points!